# Double.parse(exponential notation) is not parsing 17 digit value

Tags: parsing, exponential

Double.parse(exponential notation) is not parsing 17 digit value. I get exact same value when parsed using this method.

(from comment)
Double.Parse("7.80005E+17") gives me 7.80005E+17 instead of "780004802296598000" which is supposed to be actual value(or similar)

Comment: Can you give an example of your input, the expected output and the actual one?

Comment: Double.Parse(7.80005E+17) gives me  7.80005E+17 instead of "780004802296598000" which is supposed to be actual value(or similar)

Answer (score 0):

A `double` does have a [precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) of about 17 digits. But then you do need to *supply* those 17 digits!

`Double.Parse("7.80005E+17")` really *is* 780005_000000_000000 and not 780004_802296_598000

When you do `780004802296598000.ToString("E5")` ([limiting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#exponential-format-specifier-e) the number of digits after the decimal to 5) you do get 7.80005E+17, but then you've lost the extra digits - a "parse" will not get them back.